# Adding run times in Goovy using java.sql.Time class

Tags: java, groovy, time

I'm trying to figure out a way add run times of interviews in the system I'm working on in Groovy.

In my code I have an ArrayList of java.sql.Time objects ("times" in the below code) I would like to sum the total time of the interviews in the ArrayList with a closure. But I cannot find a valid way to add together to java.sql.Times. So, if my ArrayList contains the sql times "00:01:30" and "00:02:30" the method would return "00:04:00".

```
def sumTime(java.util.ArrayList times) {    
  def sum = java.sql.Time.valueOf("00:00:00")        
  times.each() { x ->
    //add current list member to sum              
  }
  return sum
}
```

Thanks,

Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (**edit** *this works in both the webconsole and the desktop console*):

```
import java.sql.Time

def timeList = [
  Time.valueOf( '00:01:30' ),
  Time.valueOf( '00:02:30' ),
]

def sumTime( times ) {
  long zero = Time.valueOf( '00:00:00' ).time
  new Time( zero + times.sum { it.time - zero } )
}

println sumTime( timeList )
```

which prints

```
00:04:00
```

as required

---

The original issue with this code is that on the Google App Engine JDK, `new Time( '00:00:00' ).time` returns `0`, wheras on the ex-Sun 1.6 JVM, the same code returns `-3600000`

Comment: Odd, when I run this code in TextMate I get "05:04:00", Using: Groovy Version: 1.8.0 JVM: 1.6.0_24

Comment: Weird...it works in the web console...I'll try it in the desktop console as soon as I can get to my computer...

Comment: @awful Really strange...  You were right of course, it failed on the desktop.  I have updated it with a new version.  Must be something to do with the version of the OpenJDK that the google app engine runs on...

Comment: Looks good. Thanks so much Tim, One of these days I'm really going to learn how to properly use closures.

Comment: Asked on twitter, and the problem with the original code was to do with timezones of course.  gae runs on  utc time, and I am on bst. (doh -- should have spotted that really) ;-)